# Stream audio from ios device to dlna device

Tags: ios, audio-streaming

I am experiencing problem to strem music from ios device to dlna device.

How to use the upnp in my own app, any guide?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found a link that shows how to use upnp library on ios
http://maniacdev.com/2011/09/tutorial-and-open-source-library-for-building-a-upnp-client-on-ios-devices/